# How to animate SwiftUI List order changing when using CoreData and @FetchRequest

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, core-data

I have a list of CoreData Objects retrieved from `@FetchRequest`. I am looking to animate the re-ordering of a list based on property of the object; a `Bool`.

In the code below, when you click a row item the view is rebuilt and the order changed, but this happens instantly with no animation, despite the animation on the fetch request.

I have also tried adding an animation to the `List` and `RowView`, but this also doesn't work.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct RowView: View {
    @ObservedObject var place: Place

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            place.visit()
            try? DataController.shared.container.viewContext.save()
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Text(place.wrappedName)
                Spacer()
                place.visited ? Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill") : Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ListDetailView: View {
    let list: PlaceList

    @FetchRequest var places: FetchedResults<Place>

    init(list: PlaceList) {
        self.list = list
        _places = .init(
            entity: Place.entity(),
            sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Place.visited, ascending: true)],
            predicate: NSPredicate(format: "list = %@", list),
            animation: .default
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(self.list.wrappedName)
                .font(.headline)
            List {
                ForEach(places) { place in
                    RowView(place: place)
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
struct ListDetailView: View {
let list: PlaceList

@FetchRequest var places: FetchedResults<Place>

init(list: PlaceList) {
    self.list = list
    _places = .init(
        entity: Place.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Place.visited, ascending: true)],
        predicate: NSPredicate(format: "list = %@", list),
        animation: .default
    )
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text(self.list.wrappedName)
            .font(.headline)
        List {
            ForEach(places) { place in
                RowView(place: place)
                    .animation(.default) // Add animation modifier here
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Appreciate your response, but adding the animation modifier onto RowView makes no difference at all; still no animation only instant changes.

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged, add some context to you answer by describing how it solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You need an animation block eg

```
withAnimation {
    place.visit()
    // save if you like
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the response, but this doesn't make a difference in my case. My assumption is that because the bool being toggled belongs to a CoreData object and isn't a SwiftUI binding.